# "Simple" regex doesn't work how I want it to?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What I'm trying to do is get the text and url out of a string like this:

> This is a title [http://awebsite.com/a/download.zip]

This is the regex I am using:

```
/(.*?)[(.*?)]/
```

I know what the problem is... the first `(.*?)` is matching the whole string! But I'm not sure how to only get it to match upto the first `[` occurance.

An explanation of what I'm doing wrong and how to fix would be good thank you. I **WILL** eventually learn regex!

Thanks guys

PS: using php and the `preg_match` function.

Comment: See also [Is there anything like RegexBuddy in the open source world?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) and [`/(.*?)[(.*?)]/` visualized](http://www.strfriend.com/vis?re=%2F%28.*%3F%29%5B%28.*%3F%29%5D%2F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[(.*?)]` is a character class and matches one of: `'('`, `'.'`, `'*'`, `'?'` or `')'`.

You need to escape the `[` causing it to match a literal `'['` (and the `]` is not special, so it doesn't need escaping).

```
/(.*?)\[(.*?)]/
```

See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not the first part rather the second part.

You have to escape the [ like this :

```
/(.*?)\[(.*?)]/
```

**Explanation :**

```
    "
(       # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   .       # Match any single character
      *?      # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
)
\[      # Match the character “[” literally
(       # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   .       # Match any single character
      *?      # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
)
]       # Match the character “]” literally
"
```

Comment: The `]` doesn't _have_ to be escaped.

Comment: @BartKiers :O Didn't know this. I guess because it cannot possibly be the end of a character class?

Comment: The `]` is only special if the regex engine encounters a `[` before it. So if no `[` is encountered, `]` will just match the literal `']'` It doesn't hurt to escape it though.

Comment: thanks for the info. :) knew it would be something stupid like that. :)

Comment: @ThomasClayson it's not stupid. If there weren't questions there would also be no answers :)

Answer (score 2):

You've almost got it, but try escaping the grouping characters [ and ], so you'll get:

```
/(.*?)\[(.*?)\]/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape to `[]` characters:

```
/(.*?)\[(.*?)\]/
```

Comment: The `]` doesn't _need_ to be escaped.

Comment: Ah well, it's not a bad habit. It doesn't hurt to escape it, and there are lots of people who get confused if they see an unescaped `]`... _I_ just get confused when I see an escaped `]` because I think the `]` is placed inside a character class, like this: `[a\]b]`, which matches `'a'`, `']'` or `'b'`.